# XSLT max value from XML

Tags: xslt

I am looking to get max value order identifier value from below XML.
I am getting the expected output from my code, any help would be appriciated.

Sample input XML:

```
<Orders>
  <orderLines>
    <header>
      <identifiers>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>1001</value>
      </identifiers>
    </header>
  </orderLines>
  <orderLines>
   <header>
      <identifiers>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>1002</value>
      </identifiers>
    </header>
  </orderLines>
</Orders>
```

Required output : 1002

Here is my attempt:

```
<xsl:variable name="max">
  <xsl:for-each select="//orderLines/header/identifiers/[starts-with(local-name(), 'value')]"/>
    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports - it makes a big difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<xsl:for-each select="//orderLines/header/identifiers/[starts-with(local-name(), 'value')]">` you just want `<xsl:for-each select="//orderLines/header/identifiers/value">`.

Note that XPath 2 and therefore XSLT 2 and later has a `max` function so `<xsl:variable name="max" select="max(//orderLines/header/identifiers/value)"/>` might suffice if you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.